# How to get similar behavior to bufferCount whilst emitting if there are less items than the buffer count

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to achieve something very similar to a buffer count. As values come through the pipe, bufferCount of course buffers them and sends them down in batches. I'd like something similar to this that will emit all remaining items if there are currently fewer than the buffer size in the stream.

It's a little confusing to word, so I'll provide an example with what I'm trying to achieve.

I have something adding items individually to a subject. Sometimes it'll add `1` item a minute, sometimes it'll add `1000` items in `1` second. I wish to do a long running process (`2` seconds~) on batches of these items as to not overload the server.

So for example, consider the timeline where P is processing

```
---A-----------B----------C---D--EFGHI------------------
   |_( P(A) )  |_(P(B))   |_(  P(C)  ) |_(P([D, E, F, G, H, I]))
```

This way I can process the events in small or large batches depending on how many events are coming through, but i ensure the batches remain smaller than X.

I basically need to map all the individual emits into emits that contain chunks of 5 or fewer. As I pipe the events into a `concatMap`, events will start to stack up. I want to pick these stacked up events off in batches. How can I achieve this?

Here's a stackblitz with what I've got so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iqwcbh?file=index.ts

Note how item 4 and 5 don't process until more come in and fill in the buffer. Ideally after 1,2,3 are processed, it'll pick off 4,5 the queue. Then when 6,7,8 come in, it'll process those.

Comment: Could you please include what you tried until now? and it would be easier to help you if you [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it.

Comment: Sure let me throw it in stackblitz

Comment: @AmerYousuf added, hopefully its sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I noticed the use of [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) in your sample code, I can see you are sending a request to the server for each emission (*I was originally under the impression that you were making only 1 call per batch with combined data*).

In the case of sending one request per item the solution is much simpler!

There is no need to batch the emissions, you can simply use [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) and specify its concurrency parameter.  This will limit the number of currently executing requests:

```js
const stream$ = subject$.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => doWork(val), 3),  // 3 max concurrent requests
);
```

Here is a visual of what the output would look like when the subject rapidly emits:

[image: visual of observable output]

Notice the work only starts for the first 3 items initially.  Emissions after that are queued up and processed as the prior in flight items complete.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69122873-merge?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) example of this behavior.

Comment: Amazing. 3 days of trying every solution and hack I can think of, and all I needed to do was read the documentation. Lesson learned (until next time). This nails exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: today I learned that `bufferTime` has a `maxBufferSize` parameter, that will emit when the buffer reaches that size.  Therefore, the original answer below isn't necessary, we can simply do this:

```js
const stream$ = subject$.pipe(
  bufferTime(2000, null, 3), // <-- buffer emits @ 2000ms OR when 3 items collected
  filter(arr => !!arr.length)
);
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69122873-piurad?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts)

---

ORIGINAL:

It sounds like you want a combination of [`bufferCount`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffercount) and [`bufferTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffertime).  In other words: "*release the buffer when it reaches size X or after Y time has passed*".

We can use the [`race`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race) operator, along with those other two to create an observable that emits when the buffer reaches the desired size OR after the duration has passed.  We'll also need a little help from [`take`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) and [`repeat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/repeat):

```js
const chunk$ = subject$.pipe(bufferCount(3));

const partial$ = subject$.pipe(
  bufferTime(2000),
  filter(arr => !!arr.length) // don't emit empty array
);

const stream$ = race([chunk$, partial$]).pipe(
  take(1),
  repeat()
);
```

Here we define `stream$` to be the first to emit between `chunk$` and `partial$`.  However, `race` will only use the first source that emits, so we use `take(1)` and `repeat` to sort of "*reset the race*".

Then you can do your work with `concatMap` like this:

```js
stream$.pipe(
  concatMap(chunk => this.doWorkWithChunk(chunk))
);
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69122873?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

---

You may want to roll it into a custom operator, so you can simply do something like this:

```js
const stream$ = subject$.pipe(
  bufferCountTime(5, 2000)
);
```

The definition of `bufferCountTime()` could look like this:

```js
function bufferCountTime<T>(count: number, time: number) {
  
  return (source$: Observable<T>) => {
    const chunk$ = source$.pipe(bufferCount(count));
    const partial$ = source$.pipe(
      bufferTime(time),
      filter((arr: T[]) => !!arr.length)
    );

    return race([chunk$, partial$]).pipe(
      take(1),
      repeat()
    );
  }
}
```

Another [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69122873-operator?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) sample.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. My only question is about the chances of events being missed during the `take(1), repeat()`. It unsubscribes from the source and then resubscribes. Is it possible that I could miss an event in this time? It's extremely critical I capture every single event so I don't want the possibility, but not sure about the underlying workings of rx - if it'll all be queued up on the event loop properly.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure.  That would require some testing and/or peeking into the rxjs [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/repeat.ts).  But... I just noticed the use of `forkJoin` in your sample.  Is it the case that, even though you are "batching" the emissions, you still sending separate requests to the server for each emission?  If so... there is a much simpler solution!

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR;

A StackBlitz app with the solution can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hzwpsj?file=index.ts).

---

### Explanation

Here would be an approach:

```js
const bufferLen = 3;
const count$ = subject.pipe(filter((_, idx) => (idx + 1) % bufferLen === 0));
const timeout$ = subject.pipe(
  filter((_, idx) => idx === 0),
  switchMapTo(timer(0))
);

subject
  .pipe(
    buffer(
      merge(count$, timeout$).pipe(
        take(1),
        repeat()
      )
    ),
    concatMap(buffer => forkJoin(buffer.map(doWork)))
  )
  .subscribe(/* console.warn */);

/* Output:
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3
Processed 1
Processed 2
Processed 3
Processing 4
Processing 5
Processed 4
Processed 5
Processing 6 <- after the `setTimeout`'s timer expires
Processing 7
Processing 8
Processed 6
Processed 7
Processed 8
*/
```

The idea was to still use the `bufferCount`'s behavior when items come in synchronously, but, at the same time, detect when fewer items than the chosen `bufferLen` are in the buffer. I thought that this detection could be done using a `timer(0)`, because it internally schedules a macrotask, so it is ensured that items emitted synchronously will be considered first.

However, there is no operator that exactly combines the logic delineated above. But it's important to keep in mind that we certainly want a behavior similar to the one the `buffer` operator provides. As in, we will for sure have something like `subject.pipe(buffer(...))`.

Let's see how we can achieve something similar to what `bufferTime` does, but without using `bufferTime`:

```js
const bufferLen = 3;
const count$ = subject.pipe(filter((_, idx) => (idx + 1) % bufferLen === 0));
```

Given the above snippet, using `buffer(count$)` and `bufferTime(3)`, we should get the same behavior.

Let's move now onto the *detection part*:

```js
const timeout$ = subject.pipe(
  filter((_, idx) => idx === 0),
  switchMapTo(timer(0))
);
```

What it essentially does is to start a timer after the subject has emitted its first item. This will make more sense when we have more context:

```js
subject
  .pipe(
    buffer(
      merge(count$, timeout$).pipe(
        take(1),
        repeat()
      )
    ),
    concatMap(buffer => forkJoin(buffer.map(doWork)))
  )
  .subscribe(/* console.warn */);
```

By using `merge(count$, timeout$)`, this is what we'd be saying: *when the subject emits, start adding items to the buffer and, at the same time, start the timer.* The timer is started too because it is used to determine if fewer items will be in the buffer.

Let's walk through the example provided in the StackBlitz app:

```js
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .pipe(tap(i => subject.next(i)))
  .subscribe();

// Then mimic some more items coming through a while later
setTimeout(() => {
  subject.next(6);
  subject.next(7);
  subject.next(8);
}, 10000);
```

When `1` is emitted, it will be added to the buffer and the timer will start. Then `2` and `3` arrive immediately, so the accumulated values will be emitted.
Because we're also using `take(1)` and `repeat()`, the process will restart. Now, when `4` is emitted, it will be added to the buffer and the timer will start again. `5` arrives immediately, but the number of the collected items until now is less than the given buffer length, meaning that until the 3rd value arrives, the timer will have time to finish. When the timer finishes, the `[4,5]` chunk will be emitted. What happens with `[6, 7, 8]` is the same as what happened with `[1, 2, 3]`.